# IsGUIThread -- What does it do?

Tags: winapi, ui-thread

I've been unable to figure out what `IsGUIThread` really does... I've even looked at the ReactOS source code, but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas why you might call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsGUIThread` tells you if the current thread is a GUI thread - that is a thread that is running a message loop.

What it actually does is check if the current thread has GUI thread info (see `GetGUIThreadInfo` in MSDN.

I have never used this function but one possible use I would guess is to allow code to defer slow tasks to a worker thread if the current thread is a GUI thread.

Comment: "IsGUIThread tells you if the current thread is a GUI thread"... And what is a GUI thread?

Comment: @John: I can have a non-GUI thread run a message loop too, and it works just as well (or seemingly so)...

Comment: Calling IsGUIThread(TRUE) or calling any of a number of GUI functions will make the thread a GUI thread.    Also, the main (first) thread seesm to always be a GUI thread even if you never call any GUI function.

Comment: So, effectively, calling the method is pretty much useless, right?

Comment: Calling `IsGuiThread(FALSE)` has no such side effects. A weird way to write a getter/setter pair, but it works.

Comment: Wait, but the problem is: What happens if I never call `IsGuiThread(TRUE)`, whether in the main thread or another thread, and still try to create windows? Would something crash?

Comment: No.  Calling GUI APIs like GetMessage or PeekMessage will create the GUI info and cause IsGuiThread() to return TRUE.

Comment: So my question (like it was originally) is, why would I ever need to call `IsGuiThread(TRUE)`, if it's always called automatically? (Also, sorry for the delays... I don't get notifications of replies here for some reason, so I don't see that you replied.)

Comment: The answer is slightly inaccurate: A GUI thread is a thread that has a message queue. There is no requirement for that thread to run a message loop.